# How do I divide a decimal with fixed places, rounded down?

Tags: c#

I use .NET 5.0. I want to divide a decimal `x` by an int `y` and keep the decimal place `d`, rounded down.

For example, If I want the decimal place is 3, `1M / 3 = 0.333M`, `1M / 7 = 0.142M`, etc. Of course `1M / 8 = 0.125M`, `1M / 2 = 0.5M`.

Do I have a way to do this other than like `Math.Floor(x * (int)Math.Pow(10, d) / y) / (int)Math.Pow(10, d)`?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Did you look at `decimal.Round`?

Comment: @Llama I use .NET 5.0.

Comment: @Flydog57 Does it differ from `Math.Floor()`?

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai: Yes, in that you can specify the number of decimal places, and can specify different ways of rounding mid-point values. (I would urge you to try a suggestion or at least check the documentation before asking whether it's different from a different option.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of .NET Core 3.0, you can use `MidpointRounding.ToZero` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netcore-3.0)):

> The strategy of directed rounding toward zero, with the result closest to and no greater in magnitude than the infinitely precise result.

```
decimal x = 1M;
int y = 7;
int d = 3;
decimal result = decimal.Round(x / y, d, MidpointRounding.ToZero);
Console.WriteLine(result); // outputs 0.142
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/quLIDZ)